# How to prevent IP address returned in HTML of 302 redirection?

Tags: ip

My application is leaking internal IP address through HTML of 302 redirect. I am quite stuck on the remediation.

[image: Internal IP information leakage image]

The known IIS IP address leakage issues don’t apply here since it is not using HTTP 1.0 address. The IP is not leaked in response header as well. Any remediation available that I have missed out?

Comment: If it is your application that is returning the redirect, then you need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The application should use the domain from the request headers when reconstructing redirects, rather than the remote IP when creating a response

If the redirects are send by your server, there are a couple of options, both of which can be used at the same time:

- Redirect all incoming requests to the canonical name (www.example.com) if that is not the requested domain.  This is commonly done for SEO purposes.
- Configure the server to use the canonical name in all responses.